# Empty form is not getting displayed when details are empty

Tags: angular, typescript

Here, i am trying to display the form with some detail called custominfo,two cases are important here
case-1:When custom info is present in database display form with details.
case-2:When there is no custom info details in database display empty form.
Here i am getting case-1 but i failed to get case-2,the form is not getting displayed,I really tried a lot for this but no use,can someone please help me with the solution.
My service.ts,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { IDetails } from './details';

@Injectable()
export class GetCustInfo {

    str = localStorage.getItem('social');
    loc = JSON.parse(this.str);
    id = this.loc.profile_id;
    private _productUrl = 'http://localhost/a2server/index.php/profile/editcustominfo/'+this.id;

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getCustList(): Observable<IDetails[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => { return <IDetails[]> response.json().data[0]; 
            });

    }
}
```

My main.ts(where i am subscribing to my above service),

```
     export class Custom {
     message:string = "Custom Info Updated";
   hide:any = false;
    http: Http;
   details:any;
    form: FormGroup;

     constructor(fbld: FormBuilder,http: Http,private    _service:GetCustInfo,public toastr: ToastsManager) {
    this.http = http; 
      this._service.getCustList()
        .subscribe(details => this.details = details,

                               err => this.details = {});
```

my template,

```
<div  class="col-sm-12 nopadding custominfo contenttoppadding">
    <form class="nobottommargin" *ngFor="details"  [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" name="template-contactform" action="include/sendemail.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="input-group divcenter">
                <span class="input-group-addon noradius inputgroupaddon"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></span>
                <input type="email" type="email" tooltip="Custom url" [tooltipDisabled]="false" [tooltipAnimation]="true"
                    tooltipPlacement="top" name="widget-subscribe-form-email" [formControl]="form.controls['custominfo']" [(ngModel)]="details.custominfo" class="form-control required email formcontrolheight" placeholder="Facebook" aria-required="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

interface.ts,

```
 export interface IDetails{

           custominfo:string;
               }
```

Here i am trying to display results even when values are empty but i am not able to see the form when details are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to show one form? or multiple forms?
You are using `*ngFor` ?!
And your variable `details` is an array, but your `getCustList()` function returns just the first element?

Anyway.. add error handling to your `getCustList() subscribtion`:

```
this._service.getCustList()
            .subscribe(details => this.details = details,
                       err => {
                                 this.details = [{}]; /* put your empty/default model here */
                                 console.log(err);
                              }
                       );
```

Comment: this._service.getCustList()
            .subscribe(details => this.details = details);
     
                       err => {
                                 this.details = []; /* put your empty/default model here */
                                 console.log(err);
                              }
                       Mxii,i put like this but the form is not displayying

Comment: can you please explain what is meant by empty or default model

Comment: pls clarify if you want to show one or multiple forms?

Comment: only one form...and that form is not displaying when results are empty

Comment: ok, pls change `*ngFor="details"` into `*ngIf="details"` and that error case to this: `this.details = {};` and your details variable shouldnt be an array.

Comment: mixi,i declared details:IDetails in my main.tss and when i assisgned this.details = {} it says a type error {[x:number]:undefined} is not assignable to IDetails property length is missing

Comment: see this plunker to demonstrate how it could work: https://plnkr.co/edit/QkvvQhgXLoqo2KCss5XI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks mixi,but i am still not able show the form please find the issue if u can.

Comment: here i cant make details = {} since details = IDetails[];

Comment: i am not sure why your variable is an array! would assume it like this `getCustList(): Observable<IDetails>` and `return <IDetails> response.json().data[0]` and `details:IDetails;` and `this.details = {};`

Comment: because i am using interface as IDetails

Comment: post that interface

Comment: updated that plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/QkvvQhgXLoqo2KCss5XI?p=preview please add this code to your subscribtion: `{ this.details = details; console.log(details); }` maybe there is no error, instead of just an undefined/null value !!

Comment: mixi,now i changed detailss as details:any its working

Comment: mixi,i update my code as u said in main.ts taken out the idetails can u see it

Comment: still i am not able to show the form is there any thing wrong in service

Comment: even in your example the form is not displayed

Comment: mixi,one thing here is the subscription is not going to error case